# Scrapy: missing cookies in response

Tags: python, cookies, scrapy

I've created the basic scrapy project and enabled cookiemiddleware as in [documentation](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html).

**settings.py**

```
COOKIES_ENABLED = True
COOKIES_DEBUG = True

DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
  'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware': 700  
}
```

**spiders/amazon_spider.py**

```
class AmazonSpider(Spider):
  name = "amazon_spider"
  start_urls = ['https://sellercentral.amazon.com/gp/sc-redirect']

  def parse(self, response):
      self.logger.info(response.headers.getlist('Set-Cookie'))
```

Though, for request with

```
COOKIES_ENABLED = True
```

the response is the same as for the request with

```
COOKIES_ENABLED = False
```

having

> Please Enable Cookies to Continue

in it's body.

1. Using Firefox & Firebug

> **REQUEST**
>   GET /gp/sc-redirect HTTP/1.1
>   Host: sellercentral.amazon.com
>   User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101
>   Firefox/50.0
>   Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
>   Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
>   Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
>   DNT: 1
>   Connection: keep-alive
>   Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
>   **RESPONSE**
>   HTTP/1.1 302 Found
>   Server: Server
>   Date: Mon, 30 Jan 2017 16:12:51 GMT
>   Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
>   Transfer-Encoding: chunked
>   Connection: keep-alive
>   Location: https:// sellercentral.amazon.com/ap/signin?...
>   Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
>   Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
>   Expires: 0
>   Pragma: no-cache
>   Content-Encoding: gzip
>   Set-Cookie: session-id-time=1486368000l; path=/; domain=.amazon.com; expires=Mon, 06-Feb-2017 16:12:51 GMT session-id=160-1127516-9252943; path=/; domain=.amazon.com; expires=Mon, 06-Feb-2017 16:12:51 GMT

2. Using Scrapy

> **RESPONSE**
>   DEBUG: Crawled (200) https://sellercentral.amazon.com/robots.txt> (referer: None)
>   DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to https://sellercentral.amazon.com/ap/signin?...> from https://sellercentral.amazon.com/gp/sc-redirect/>
>   DEBUG: Received cookies from: <302 https:// sellercentral.amazon.com/ap/signin?...> 
>   Set-Cookie: signin-sso-state-us=44538bf3-88d0-410b-9aa0-bc8da4b2d090; Domain=.amazon.com; Expires=Sun, 25-Jan-2037 16:09:14 GMT; Path=/ap/; Secure; HttpOnly
>   Set-Cookie: ap-fid=""; Domain=.amazon.com; Expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970
>   00:00:10 GMT; Path=/ap/; Secure

Here are the full [log](http://pastebin.com/yTjpwZsi) and full final [response body](http://pastebin.com/28TZX1bq).

Why the Set-Cookie results are different and how to handle cookies with Scrapy for this particular case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After adding

```
USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0'
```

to the `settings.py` it worked fine and did not complain about disabled cookies.

The new response is

> DEBUG: Crawled (200) https://sellercentral.amazon.com/robots.txt> (referer: None)
>   Received cookies from: <302 https: //sellercentral.amazon.com/gp/sc-redirect/>
>   Set-Cookie: session-id-time=1486368000l; path=/; domain=.amazon.com; expires=Mon, 06-Feb-2017 23:14:58 GMT
>   Set-Cookie: session-id=167-3010519-3678460; path=/; domain=.amazon.com; expires=Mon, 06-Feb-2017 23:14:58 GMT
>   DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to https: //sellercentral.amazon.com/ap/signin?...> from https: //sellercentral.amazon.com/gp/sc-redirect/>